# AngularJS login interceptor crashing chrome

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My website uses AngularJS and UI Router everywhere except for the login page. To redirect a user to the login page when their session expires, I have the following interceptor

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('authInterceptor', ['$q', function ($q) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },

        'response': function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                window.location.href = "App/Signin";
                return $q.reject(response);

            } else {
                return response || $q.when(response);
            }
        },

        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                window.location.href = "App/Signin";
            }

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Sometimes, this code causes Chrome to fall into a redirect loop and crash. Clicking on the reload button resolves the problem. I suspect that UI router is trapping the redirect to the login page and trying to set the state back to the default. Is there a way I can redirect to the login page without having UI router interfere?

Comment: We are having this exact same issue too. It is only happening on some machines though. The majority of our users are not having an issue, but some it happens every time, but they can refresh after the crash and its fine.
Any luck figuring this out?

Answer (score 2):

The loop caused by the fact that redirect to the login page launch another redirection recursivley

Please add the following to match your scenario

```
  if (response.status === 401 && $location.path() != 'App/Signin')
```

And to make it clean, use the $state service, for example:

```
  $state.go('login-signin-state')
```

Comment: The login page does not use AngularJS and UI router and is separate from my single page app which is why I have used window.location.href instead of $state.go().

Comment: Hoo OK @user1, did it fix it?

Comment: No - I am still seeing the same crash in Chrome.

Comment: No error in the console but I see the Chrome aw snap page like the one shown in this image http://www.dedoimedo.com/images/computers_years/2013_1/google-chrome-aw-snap.jpg Clicking the reload option usually resolves it

Comment: Monitor you network tab in the debugger while refreshing, you'll see a repeated request sent, what is it?

Comment: I use Fiddler and I see no requests which is why I suspect that UI Router is trapping the redirect to the login page. I do see the URL bar on Chrome flicker before it crashes.

Comment: Same for us, no network requests, no console messages.

Comment: @DustinBrooks - Hey Dustin. I was finally able to solve my problem by removing the default state in UI router. Looks like the default state was getting triggered when attempting to navigate to the login page causing an endless redirect loop in Chrome.